# How to find string from list of variables python

Tags: python, function, loops, find

I am new to Stackoverflow and New to programming so the question I will ask is probably very basic.

I wanted to know out of a list of variables how can I find the types of variables.

For example, I have a function:

```
def list_of_variables(w,x,y,z):
```

Now I could use the **type()** function. But I was wondering how will I be able to extract all the strings from that **list_of_variables** using the **type()** function.

Should I use a loop function to go through each variable? But in my opinion that would be a bit messy.

Is there a better and much cleaner way to approaching the problem.

Thank you everyone for your time!

Comment: Why does this matter in the first place?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams .. Lol, thats a nice philosophical question indeed. Well Why does anything matter? Probably because of objective reality and the subjectivity we have created in our lives, i.e:learning programming.

Comment: What you're asking isn't "learning programming", it's performing stupid software tricks. The question is **why do you want to perform such a broken task in the first place?**

Comment: Well its because, I am making a function that takes in variables such as student name, number and age. But when the user inputs these values, they may not be in order. So I wanted to find which variable is what. And then return the inputed values in a particular order... such as (age, Student Name, Number)

Comment: Not in order? What the hell? Check if a number is a number, and if not then tell them that they screwed up and to try again.

Comment: humm.. I see what you are saying... **Keep It Simple Stupid (K.I.S.S)**.

Comment: One can learn many things by learning software tricks. Learning programming may not have been the best answer, but "Learning Python", this definitely is.

Comment: Why would you allow a user to give values in an arbitrary order?

Comment: In your case (=> "student name, number and age"), relying on type to infer semantic is brittle at best - "number" and "age" should both be integers so you cannot tell one from the other, and if your users aren't even able to pass the arguments in the right order, they might as well pass in strings for "number" and "age"... Don't try and guess, educate your users instead. Oh and yes: Python has support for named arguments too...

Answer (score 2):

You can use list expression with `isinstance`.

**Short Way**

`stringlist = [item for item in (w,x,y,z) if isinstance(item, str)]`

**Long Way**

```
stringlist = []
for item in (w,x,y,z):
    if isinstance(item str):
        stringlist.append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehensions to go through it without it looking horrible, but under the hood it's just a fancy way of writing a for loop (and actually explicitly uses one).

```
def list_of_variables(w,x,y,z):
    """Returns a list of all the variables which are strings"""
    return [var for var in [w,x,y,z] if isinstance(var,str)]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def list_of_variables(w,x,y,z):
    retlist = []
    for var in [w,x,y,z]:
        if isinstance(var,str):
            retlist.append(var)
    return retlist
```

We can actually simplify this by using *args, which will catch all arguments passed to the function, whether there is 1 or 100,000!

```
def list_of_variables(*args):
    """Returns a list featuring all the arguments which are strings"""
    return [var for var in args if isinstance (var,str)]
```